# json response to python variable

Tags: python, json

In the following code (a html response), do I need to remove the "M18.high_52 = {" in the beginning and the "}" (in the very end) in order to assign it under a python json variable? Thanks!

Update:
I just want to get the securityCode and securityShortName. Both already done and I just want to see it could be simply it and not using the

x = r.text.replace("M18.high_52 = " ,"")

to assign to json.

```
M18.high_52 = {
    "stockBeans" : [
        {
                "securityCode" : "00176",
                "yearHigh" : "0.218",
                "yearLow" : "0.121",
                "percentageChange" : 14.737,
                "priceChange" : 0.028,
                "securityShortName" : "SUPERACTIVE GP",
                "securityNameGCCS" : "先機企業集團",
                "previousClosingPrice" : "0.19",
                "nominalPrice" : "0.218",
                "sharesTraded" : "400000",
                "turnover" : "80726",
                "highPrice" : "0.22",
                "lowPrice" : "0.19"
        }
        ,{
                "securityCode" : "00532",
                "yearHigh" : "0.71",
                "yearLow" : "0.49",
                "percentageChange" : 20.339,
                "priceChange" : 0.12,
                "securityShortName" : "WKK INTL (HOLD)",
                "securityNameGCCS" : "王氏港建國際",
                "previousClosingPrice" : "0.59",
                "nominalPrice" : "0.71",
                "sharesTraded" : "1122000",
                "turnover" : "749480",
                "highPrice" : "0.72",
                "lowPrice" : "0.63"
        }
    ],
    "stockBeans.size" : 37
}
```

Update:

```
import json
import requests


###
def update52wHigh():
  r = requests.get("http://money18.on.cc/js/real/52highlow/high_securityCode_b5_asc.js")
  r.encoding = 'big5-hkscs'
  x = r.text.replace("M18.high_52 = " ,"")
  j = json.loads(x)

  print (j["stockBeans"][0]["securityNameGCCS"])

  importList = []
  stockList = []

  x=0
  for stockBean in j["stockBeans"]:
    stockName = stockBean["securityNameGCCS"]
    stockNo = stockBean["securityCode"]
    stockPrice = stockBean["nominalPrice"]
    stockTurnover = stockBean["turnover"]
    stockPercentageChange = stockBean["percentageChange"]

    print (stockNo + " " +stockName)
    if float(stockPrice) > 1:
      stockList.append([])
      stockList[x].append(stockNo)
      stockList[x].append(stockPrice)


      importList.append((stockNo,stockName,stockPrice,stockTurnover,stockPercentageChange))
      x=x+1


update52wHigh()
```

Comment: See [the standard library `json` module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.

Comment: You could explain your goal in your post to make it more understandable

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove anything..You already have a response

This show work

```
import json
import requests

string_res = response.read().decode('utf-8')
json_object = json.loads(string_res)
```